# Rails how create association in the model before or after create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm using a callback to create a  association but after the creation did not associate

Someone have any hint how associate in the model instead of in the controller?

```
class Open < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :images_build

  def images_build
    images.build

    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to create an association and save it to the database then do:

```
before_create ->{ images.build }
```

This will create a single image record associated with your new Open record.

Comment: All these years I was creating a method. This is great, thank you!

Comment: Brilliant, Thx a lot.